# What are the most common ways of method invocation in client-server architecture?

Tags: java, client-server

I want to implement (for my first time) a server for a simple Java application and an Android app.
I read about EJB and web services, but I'd like to know what are the all common ways of implementing a server and communication between client and server (Json, EJB etc...).
A list of possible ways will be sufficient ( I'll find resources by myself).

Comment: what is the use case?

Comment: You are providing not enough Information to give you sophisticated advice. Additionally to sidgate's question, you should add if this is going to be a production App or just a Little "playground for learning" and what the backend should provide (DB-Access? How much Throughput? Streaming media? Just 1 or 2 methods with small data??)

Comment: @sidgate - the use case is just simple logic that should query database, manipulate the data and return list of objects or only one object via json format or other possibility.

Comment: take a look at Spring Rest

Comment: @Fildor My app is just for learning. Not production. It includes db access but not streaming media. Do you have any recommendations ?

Comment: If you want to learn, implement as much as you can yourself. If you want to learn a Framework use that framework. If you want to concentrate on Android development you probably should fire up a REST Server as easily as possible. That is use some Container like JBoss, Tomcat ... or Frameworks like Spring to set something up against which you can implement Android. OR just use some public REST API to consume on Android (wheather, finance data ... there are plenty). So, short answer: depends on what you want to learn exactly.